# Make one page inaccessible to search engine spiders

Tags: search-engines

To prevent spiders from accessing a page one can just add  within  tags. Is there a way in WordPress to achieve this, for one page in particular, through some plugin or even from the native dashboard?

Comment: Just use a *"robots.txt"*.

Comment: Sure but I'm looking for a solution that some non tech savvy client could use.

Comment: How tech savvy do you have to be to drop a text file into a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) is set up to do this for you on a per-page basis. If you aren't using Yoast already, I'd strongly recommend it - there are advanced controls for SEO, indexing, redirecting, etc.

Comment: And sometimes, a non-tech savvy answer is needed..

Answer (score 5):

- First, create an *"example.com/robots.txt"* file in that location.
- Second, write these directives in your *"robots.txt"* file:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /the-page/that-you-want-to-disallow.html
  ```
- Third, that's it! *"/the-page/that-you-want-to-disallow.html"* is now inaccessible to search engine spiders, except malware robots.

For more info, visit [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to add a `tag` or `category`, and name it 'nofollow'.
You could then use a [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in your theme's function.php and add

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

to the outputs of the [wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action.

For example:

```
if(is_tag('nofollow')){
    add_action('wp_head', 'wp_head_nofollow');
}

function wp_head_nofollow(){
    echo '<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">' ;
}
```

code not tested but I think you get the gist.

More elegant solution would be to add a metabox to posts/pages with a checkbox to 'block spiders' on and off and do about the same thing as with the conditional tag.